# QEMU/KVM: How to configure a writeable shared folder for guest, which itself is a CIFS mounted network share on host?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, kvm, qemu, libvirt

### Issue

I am having a hard time configuring a shared folder with write permissions inside the guest. My special case is that the shared folder references a CIFS network share mounted on the host.

### Host configuration

Network share (and shared folder) `/media/nas/temp` is mounted via

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=dave,vers=3.0,uid=dave,gid=libvirt-qemu //nas/temp /media/nas/temp
```

Virt-manager configuration:

[image]

Permissions from host perspective:

```
dave@host:~$ ll /media/nas/
drwxr-xr-x 2 dave        libvirt-qemu    0 Dez  6 15:36 temp/
```

### Guest configuration

`/temp` (`/media/nas/temp` on host) is mounted via:

```
sudo mount -t 9p -o trans=virtio,version=9p2000.L /temp /media/temp
```

Permissions from guest perspective (64055 is the uid of `libvirt-qemu` group of the host):

```
dave@guest:~$ ll /media
drwxr-xr-x  2 dave 64055    0 dec  6 15:36 temp/
```

### Problem

A write operation like creating a new file triggers following error:

```
dave@guest:~$ touch /media/temp/myfile.log
touch: cannot touch '/media/temp/myfile.log': Permission denied
```

I also tried `file_mode` and `dir_mode` mount options from the host:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=dave,vers=3.0,uid=dave,gid=libvirt-qemu,\
  file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 //nas/temp /media/nas/temp
```

New permissions from host perspective:

```
dave@host:~$ ll /media/nas
drwxrwxrwx 2 dave        libvirt-qemu    0 Dez  6 15:36 temp/
```

Curiously, now I get a different error:

```
dave@guest:~$ touch /media/temp/myfile.log
touch: cannot touch '/media/temp/myfile.log': Operation not supported
```

### What works

1. The host can write to `/media/nas/temp` with user `dave`.
2. From within the guest, I could mount via CIFS directly successfully (same credentials) - but that is not possible in my current environment.
3. I am also able to mount a local host folder (like `/home/dave/Downloads/qemu-test`, which has the exact same permissions, and write to it. Permissions in this case were:

```
dave@host:~$ ll ~/Downloads/
drwxrwx---+  2 dave libvirt-qemu    4096 Dez  6 17:25 qemu-test/
```

### Question

Why does it make a difference, if I want to share a network or local folder via `mount -t 9p`? As shown, the permissions should be the same and it shouldn't matter for the guest, what kind of mountpoint is shared (?).

Has anybody managed to do write a shared folder mounted as network share from host (if yes, how)?

### Related

- follow-up post of [How to use QEMU/KVM virtual machine disk image on SMB/CIFS network share: Permission denied](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/622194/how-to-use-qemu-kvm-virtual-machine-disk-image-on-smb-cifs-network-share-permis)

Similar posts, which are about sharing a local folder:

- [How can I store files in the mounted shared folder?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257372/how-can-i-store-files-in-the-mounted-shared-folder)
- [serverfault: KVM guest cannot write to 9p share owned by non-root](https://serverfault.com/questions/559726/kvm-guest-cannot-write-to-9p-share-owned-by-non-root)
- [serverfault: Read/write access for passthrough (9p) filesystems with libvirt/qemu?](https://serverfault.com/questions/342801/read-write-access-for-passthrough-9p-filesystems-with-libvirt-qemu)
- [askubuntu: 9p (libvirt/QEMU) share modes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772784/9p-libvirt-qemu-share-modes)

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more investigation, here is what worked for me. Important points:

1. set mount mode to Squash - neither Passthrough nor Mapped.
2. set mount point owner to libvirt-qemu and the group to dave (user/uid used in the guest).
3. set `file_mode=0755`, `dir_mode=0755` in the mount CIFS options.

Example mount (host):

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=dave,vers=3.11,uid=libvirt-qemu,gid=dave,file_mode=0775,dir_mode=0775 //nas/temp /media/nas/temp
```

Ad 1.: In other modes, I got errors like

> touch: setting times of xxx: No such file or directory
>
> touch: cannot touch '/media/temp/myfile.log': Operation not supported

Ad 2.: It wasn't sufficient to set libvirt-qemu as group, resulting in "Permission denied" errors. In the question, I did it the other way round. Make sure to select the correct UID for the guest - e.g. set the same UIDs for dave on the host and guest. Note: the QEMU/KVM virtual machine is run as user libvirt-qemu.

Ad 3.: These options make the mountpoint writeable for user dave, whose group is set as owning group (standard would be readonly).